# Show Native Ad OnBackpressed

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, facebook-audience-network

I'm trying to show a Facebook Audience Network Native Ad onBackPressed i have added all the Layouts but i don't know how to implement it and this is my OnBackPressed code :

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
            .setTitle("Closing")
            .setMessage("Are you sure you want to Exit?")
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, which -> finish() })
            .setNegativeButton("No", null)
            .show()
}
```

i Want to implement a Native Facebook Audience Network Ad on the Dialog i have Created the Native Ad Layouts as Described Here : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/guides/ad-formats/native/android

But i really don't know how to do this , Can you help me with this Please

This is a Screenshot of the OnBackPressed Dialog

[Screenshot : When i want native ad to be shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZOFL.png)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.setView()` to change the dialog layout.

It would look something like this:

```java
public void onBackPressed() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
            .setTitle("Closing")
            .setView(R.layout.your_custom_layout)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, which -> finish() })
            .setNegativeButton("No", null);

    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();

    //Here you can use dialog.findViewById()
}
```

Sorry I don't know Kotlin, but it will be similar.